# Disabling buffer-specific swap file creation in Neovim using Lua

Tags: lua, editor, neovim

How can one disable the creation of swap files (`.swp`) for a specific buffer in Neovim using Lua?

The intended use case is to create a "scratch" buffer that can be used for holding the output of certain commands. This output is not critical nor does it need to persist, hence a `.swp` file is not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable swap files for a specific buffer in Neovim, one can use:

```lua
local bufnr = vim.api.nvim_get_current_buf()
vim.api.nvim_buf_set_option(bufnr, "swapfile", false)
```

If one is looking to permanently disable swap file creation in Neovim (generally not recommended), add the following line to your configuration file:

```lua
vim.opt.swapfile = false
```